# How to understand ひと断ちにする

Tags: words

私がこの男をたしなめ大差で**ひと断ちにし**てみせます

Originally I understood this phrase as "I will rebuke this man, cut him in two with a great difference (in score)" but have not been able to sufficiently break down my understanding of ひと断ちにする to my own satisfaction.

I originally read ひと断ちにする as similar to 一太刀にする (although 一太刀 actually taking にする seems to be rare according to exact google search) but that may not be correct.

To my understanding 断つ means to sever something, so I think 断ち is its noun form, making ひと断ち one slice by my reasoning, so I think literally he's saying that he will take him in one slice by a great difference.

Am I on the right track or am I missing something?

[image: sai declares his intention to punish a bully with a taste of his own medicine]

EDIT: I should have made this more clear. 佐為 is talking about figuratively slicing someone in a game of go. It's not literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ひと断ちにする is any common saying, but we can somewhat grasp its gist as some admixture of the following popular idioms:

- [ひとひねりにする](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/186228/meaning/m0u/) "subdue by a single wrench" (= defeat easily)
- [ひと打ちにする](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/185868/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%B2%E3%81%A8%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1/) "knock down at a blow"
- [一刀両断する](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%80%E5%88%80%E4%B8%A1%E6%96%AD/) "cut in two with a single slash" (= cut the Gordian knot; take merciless measures)

So it would mean something like "put down (easily) with a slash of the sword", but not knowing the plot, I can't decide whether the ひと断ち is intended to be a literal stroke of blade runs through his body, or figurative break of his spirit, will to fight etc.

Also, 大差 is "great difference" but this word is likely used for gap in amount nowadays, so it sounds most natural when he mentions some kind of scored match (again, not knowing the plot).

Comment: Him, actually. I'm pretty sure that's サイ of ヒカルの碁. A go-playing spirit from the Heian Period. And you're right about 大差 referring to a score: he's talking about 地合; the difference in the (resulting) [territory](https://senseis.xmp.net/?Territory).

Comment: @Will Thank you for your input! Now at least it's clear that I fell into a trap and didn't read the question carefully.

Comment: Yeah all of my questions are from ヒカルの碁。 In this context 佐為 is actually talking about punishing someone for using go to bully a weaker player, (by playing him in a game). (Maybe I should have just linked the whole page but was afraid of being annoying) In other words you are right, it's figurative.

Answer (score 0):

ひと断ちにする means to cut the person down.

大差で refers to the big differences in the skills of the two people.

The speaker is planning to teach him a lesson, cut him down and show him the difference in their skills.

Comment: You make it sound as if ひと断ちにする were a common expression when it is not.

Comment: That's right l'électeur. it's not a common expression (certainly not talked about on the internet, I did a number of searches and found no explanation in japanese or english) which is why I had trouble breaking it down.

Comment: I am not satisfied with this answer because it only provides a general understanding of what the phrase means, which I already have. I am hoping to correctly understand the phrase's component semantic parts and how they work together grammatically. Welcome to japanese stackexchange, by the way.

Comment: Alright. You’re right it’s not common, but if you watch 時代劇 we can hear this phrase being used. 人たちにしてやるとか。 This comes from the kunyomi きる。人との関係を断ち切るとか。cut off relations with someone. 人たちにするというのは人を切ること。切って捨てること。 しっぽを断ち切る cut off the tail. However, since it is illegal to own a samurai sword, you are not likely to hear this word in casual conversation. And thus, we can hear or see this word on TV, or in manga.

Comment: If this character says 人たちにして without みせます or やる。 Then, 大変なことになるよ。 Someone might stand up and take your offer.  Please cut me! Yikes.

Comment: Thank you for adding interesting context @Keichan 

So are you saying that 人たち is the same as ひと断ち , and so am I wrong that ひと means 一 in this case, and therefore that I should be reading it as 人断ちにしてみせます, meaning to "cut off" a person?

Are you also saying that 「にしてやる」や「にしてみせる」など is replacing きる？

Comment: 時代劇 context sounds relevant since the person speaking is originally from the Heian Era and was last conscious in the Edo era

Comment: @Janusz Yes, ひと is person in this context. He has decided 〜ことにするto cut this person with his sword. 人断ちにする=人を切ることにする。すごいね。Lit. I have decided to do the act of cutting this person. でも、so, if the sentence ends with て、whether or not he decided to kill the person, or is asking someone to cut him down is not clear. Thus long ago, they added やる so we know it’s not a command/request.

Comment: The sentence ends as てみせます so I believe he's declaring his determination to cut him down. Also in context, he says he will do this in a game of go, not literally. If you could edit your comments into your answer and rewrite them to be clearer as to how they answer my question, that would be very helpful, thank you ^^

Comment: That makes sense. He has decided to take this guy down a notch and show him the differences in their abilities.

Comment: `He has decided 〜ことにする to cut this person with his sword. 人断ちにする=人を切ることにする` <-- えっ・・  You mean..「ひと断ち」＝「人断ち」？? and.. are you saying the にする in 「この男をひと断ち**にする** 」 has something to do with 「～こと**にする** 」"decide to ~~" ?? 　「やつの心臓を[一突]{ひとつ}き**にする** 」「やつをメッタ刺し**にする** 」「やつを八つ裂き**にする** 」とかと同じ「～にする」ですけど・・

Comment: 僕を救ってありがとうございましたね、@Chocolateさん…ちょっと困っちゃったね… Thank you for rescuing me Chocolateさん, I am a little embarrassed...

Comment: So I am right after all that ひと断ち is in fact 一断ち and moreover; it turns out that number + masu stem + にする is a form...